# List file not found in open cv

Tags: iphone

I am new to using `open cv`, I have downloaded the `open cv- 2.4.7.tar.gz` using the following link:  [Open CV Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.3.1/)

I have used the following commands in Terminal:

```
tar xvf OpenCV-2.4.7.tar.gz
cd OpenCV-2.4.7
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
sudo make install
```

When making a demo in `open cv` it is installed successfully.

I add the `open cv` framework and  in the `prefix.pch` file I add the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
#define __OPENCV_BACKGROUND_SEGM_HPP__
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <list>
```

but I get the error:

```
list file not found
```

The error is located in the `background_segm.hpp` class. I do not know where the `background_segm.hpp` class is in `Xcode`.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I have first changed the file extensions from `.m` to `.mm`, because they are C++ files.

Example:

- `Viewcontroller.m` to `Viewcontroller.mm`
- `Appdelegate.m` to `Appdelegate.mm`

I was also using the old `opencv` framework, to fix this I have:

- downloaded the new `opencv2` framework
- added it into my project
- added this to the header search path: `/usr/local/include/opencv2`
- added the required frameworks: Coreimage, Corevideo,ImageI/o, AVFoundation, etc...